# Terminal commands don't work when executed using Python

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system

I am trying to perform certain tasks via a Python script. These are simple Terminal commands.

```
os.system("cd ~/Desktop/Watched/")
os.system("rm -rf dist")
os.system("rm -rf setup.py")
os.system("rm -rf ~/Desktop/gui.app")

os.system("py2applet --make-setup gui.py")
os.system("python3 setup.py py2app -A")

os.system("mv dist/gui.app ~/Desktop")

os.system("rm -rf dist")
os.system("rm -rf setup.py")
```

When I run this program from within an IDE, the `.app` file that is made opens as expected, without any errors. However, when I run this program from the Terminal like :
`python3 ~/Desktop/Watched/make-app.py`, I get the following error when I try to open the `.app` file:

[image: Error message]

How can I fix this?

Comment: don't you get any error message in terminal ?

Comment: No error messages. It runs in the terminal as usual. Only while opening the app, I have an issue

Comment: you could add `print()` before every command to recognize which one make problem.

Comment: did you run `.app` manually in terminal ? It may display any error message in terminal.

Comment: I did run ```open gui.app``` in the terminal. I get the same error. I also added a print statement before every command. The code runs as expected. The issue I am facing is while I'm opening the app (both via terminal and normally)